# Query to select a common record from multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables namely

1. 'recruitment',
2. 'project',
3. 'position'.

All these three tables are using primary key of another table **'template'**.

Now, I want to fetch the count of records from all the three tables that are using "templateId" in them.

Comment: so `join` them, `group` them and `count` them?

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: Add sample data and what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(recruitment.templateId),
    COUNT(project.templateId),
    COUNT(position.templateId),
FROM
    template
    LEFT JOIN recruitment
        ON template.templateId=recruitment.templateId
    LEFT JOIN project
        ON template.templateId=project.templateId
    LEFT JOIN recruitment
        ON position.templateId=position.templateId
```

Comment: You might want to use a left join here